# server with multi purpose possible?

Tags: nas, windows-server-2012, voip

I would like to have the following 3 uses available to me.

- Accessing my files within and outside my network
- Game servers occasionally; Minecraft or Gmod (as example)
- Teamspeak 3

Is it possible to have this all within 1 running server?

Also a server CPU seems quite expensive, won't a normal low i3 do the job for a server with these purposes?

Comment: A server is just a computer.  All of those tasks can be done with a desktop, so it can be done with a server, question does not seem well researched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have anything you want running on a server, including multiple services, if the hardware will handle what you want the services to do.

Security is more a concern, if there is a vulnerability in one service, and an attacker gains access to the system, the attacker can ruin other services as well.  So if someone manages to hack into your Minecraft server, they might be much more easily able to do nasty things to your personal files, for example.

Virtualization or virtualization-like things such as containers, jails, etc. can mitigate this.  If you only have game servers running occasionally this also helps from a security point of view.

You would simply have to try it, or find out what all these services need and configure your hardware accordingly.  The CPU is probably not an issue as much as the amount of RAM and ...

... one thing you are not considering is your network speed - your residential network connection (your upload speed, which is what the outside uses to access, is always much less than your download speed) is likely going to be the bottleneck with performance.  Furthermore your router will be burdened with additional incoming traffic which can affect others on your home network.  You should also review the security and QoS settings in your router (you'll have to anyway for port forwarding) and make sure it is meeting your needs.